# How to find the RAM size in Red Hat Linux Server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I am trying to find the command to show the installed memory (RAM) in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.5.

I have found the following command:

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
```

But it looks like the MemTotal value is not the actual RAM value. 
I want to know the real RAM of the system (similar to Installed memory(RAM) in Windows).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you think that value is wrong?

Comment: That value should be correct.

Comment: @AndrewStubbs because he wrote `meminofo` :-)

Comment: The value is really big, all other servers here that I have seen here is has less  RAM memory. I thought all servers has same configuration. But I was wrong with my assumption, the meminfo value is correct. This particular server has more RAM.  Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: @AndrewStubbs, Thanks for your  correction.I should follow the basic rules before posting any questions.

Comment: If it's a HP server with HP Tools installed: `sudo hpasmcli -s "show server" | grep "^Memory"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the `free` command, which will tell you the total/used/free amounts of RAM you have, the `-m` flag will display it in MB:

```
free -m
```

Though I think it just uses the same source as `/proc/meminfo` behind the scenes so you may get the same answer.